# Reading JSON properties in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm having trouble reading properties from JSON within NodeJS.

Feels like an obvious mistake I may be making..

The JSON is from this endpoint;

http://hypem.com/playlist/history/faisdotal/json/1/data.js

My code:

```
var request = require('request');

request("http://hypem.com/playlist/history/faisdotal/json/1/data.js", function (err, res, json) {
  JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(json["1"]["artist"]);  // undefined
});
```

~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
json = JSON.parse(json);
```

It won't (and can't) simply update the value of the parameter. The `.parse()` routine **returns** the value parsed from the string you pass it.

JavaScript is purely call-by-value, so there's really no way it could possibly work the way your code is written.

Comment: How awkward, I tried this at first but it didn't work which lead me to just using JSON.parse(json) bare. Thanks.

Comment: "JavaScript is purely call-by-value" -- [this is not true](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass).  Primitive types are passed by value, objects are passed by reference.

Comment: No, that is false, @josh3736.  Objects are **always** references in **every** context in JavaScript. The **references** are passed by value, and that is the only way an object is "real" in JavaScript.  Trust me, it is definitely a purely call-by-value language in the strict sense of that term.

Comment: Right, but aren't all references "passed by value" in any language?  Besides, saying that *objects* are passed "by value" is misleading.  `var obj = { a:1 }; function inc(o) { o.a++; }; inc(obj);` - `obj.a` is `2`.  If `o` had by-value semantics, you'd expect `obj.a` to still be `1` since `inc` would get a value (copy), not a reference to the original.  You obviously can't do `o=0` in `inc` to change what `obj` points to, but you can modify any of its properties *so long as the argument `o` was not a primitive type.*  For example, `var obj = 'string'; inc(obj);`, `obj.a` is undefined.

Comment: @josh3736 you must understand that the terms "call-by-value" and "call-by-reference" have distinct meanings in discussions of programming language design, meanings that are not quite in line with colloquial usage. Read any authority you like: JavaScript is a purely call-by-value language.

Answer (score 5):

You need to store the returned value of JSON.parse:

```
json = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json["1"]["artist"]);
```